# Trying to read csv dataset into tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have csv files(train and test) that contains data in the following format

[image]

I am trying to load my data (100MB) into tensorflow input pipeline (not sure if this is the right way to do it).

```
  x, y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,2]), tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,1])
 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

train_dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(csv_path+'\csvdatatrain.csv', batch_size=32)
test_dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(csv_path+'\csvdatatest.csv', batch_size=32)


iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
features, labels = iter.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #initialise iterator with train data
    sess.run(iter.initializer, feed_dict={x: train_dataset[0], y: train_dataset[1]})

    for _ in range(EPOCHS):
        #### Training
        print('This is training')

        #### Testing
        sess.run(iter.initializer, feed_dict={ x: test_dataset[0], y: test_dataset[1]})
        print('This is testing')
```

I am getting an error while initializing iterator with train data

> sess.run(iter.initializer, feed_dict={ x: train_dataset[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q26wq.png), y: train_dataset [0]}) 
>   TypeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a placeholder if you are gonna use tensorflow data loader. You either load the csv file with numpy and pass it to the placeholders through `feed_dict` or use tensorflow data loader and only pass the path to csv file.

If you're gonna use tensorflow data loader, you don't need to init the iterator every epoch! it is only initialized one time and no `feed_dict` is needed there.

This code works with me on tensorflow 1.8 (used [iris dataset](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjsh_7z8N7cAhVGZawKHWK6B08QFjACegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fuiuc-cse%2Fdata-fa14%2Fgh-pages%2Fdata%2Firis.csv&usg=AOvVaw0hydw3qxMU2WonZayhU2Qp) there)

```
EPOCHS = 10
dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset('iris.csv',batch_size=1)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_elemnet = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    for _ in range(EPOCHS):
        print(sess.run(next_elemnet))
```

The output should look like so:

```
{'sepal_length': array([ 6.4000001], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 2.79999995], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 5.5999999], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 2.20000005], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'virginica'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 5.19999981], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 2.70000005], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 3.9000001], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 1.39999998], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'versicolor'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 4.80000019], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 3.4000001], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 1.89999998], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 0.2], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'setosa'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 7.69999981], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 2.79999995], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 6.69999981], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 2.], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'virginica'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 4.4000001], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 3.], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 1.29999995], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 0.2], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'setosa'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 5.], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 3.], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 1.60000002], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 0.2], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'setosa'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 6.4000001], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 3.20000005], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 5.30000019], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 2.29999995], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'virginica'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 4.5], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 2.29999995], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 1.29999995], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 0.30000001], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'setosa'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 5.], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 3.5], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 1.60000002], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 0.60000002], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'setosa'], dtype=object)}
{'sepal_length': array([ 6.], dtype=float32), 'sepal_width': array([ 2.20000005], dtype=float32), 'petal_length': array([ 5.], dtype=float32), 'petal_width': array([ 1.5], dtype=float32), 'species': array([b'virginica'], dtype=object)}
```